# Understanding how to select the Range for a scale

Tags: d3.js

This code and explanation:

Let us generate the basic SVG viewport and use that as our selection:

```
 //Create the SVG Viewport selection
 var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                      .attr("width", 400)
                                      .attr("height", 100);

 //Create the Scale we will use for the Axis
 var axisScale = d3.scale.linear()
                          .domain([0, 100])
                          .range([0, 400]);

//Create the Axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                  .scale(axisScale);
```

Three things to note before we go on:

The width of the SVG Viewport is 400 units
We want to map the numbers of 0 to 100 (.domain([0, 100]))
onto the width of the view port - which is 400 units
**So we define the range of the scale as .range([0, 400])**

I still can't understand the rational behind how he figured out what to put for the domain and range of the Scale?   Can someone explain it a little better?

Comment: Could you clarify if you want to know the reasoning behind domain/range semantics or the mechanics of the implementation?

Comment: How did he know he needs those domain and ranges for the axisScale based on the values he had for svgContainer width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 provides `domain` and `range` helpers to allow you to project your data onto a canvas of some sort. **Domain defines your input**, while **range defines the output**.

Suppose you have a set of values where each value is between 0 and 100. This is your domain, expressed in d3 as `domain([0, 100])`. Now suppose you want to display these values graphically. For example as svg circles. You could map your values directly to pixels (e.g. value 10 translates to 10px left, 10px top) but your svg container could be much larger, or smaller than 100px wide/high.

To make use of the available space, you define the range. For an svg container of 500px wide and 300px high your range would be `[0, 500]` for scale "x" and `[0, 300]` for scale "y" (if you plot starting from top left corner). Scaled values will fit into these ranges.

Here's an example:

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, 500]);

scale(0);   // 0
scale(100); // 500
scale(50);  // 250

scale(-1);  // -5
```

Further reading:

- http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2011/08/11/d3-scales-and-color/
- http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/scales/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics)